# I am getting an error while loading shared libraries libXm.so.3

Tags: libraries

I have installed a program called Swiss PDB. Upon running the program I get the error:

```
/usr/share/SPDBV/bin/spdbv.Linux: error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have used apt-file search libXm.so.3 which gives the output:

```
libxm4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXm.so.3
```

The file itself is a Link to shared library (application/x-sharedlib). With the link target as libXm.so.4.0.4

I'm not sure how to make this program run without getting the error? How do I tell the program where the the shared library is?

*file /usr/share/SPDBV/bin/spdbv.Linux
/usr/share/SPDBV/bin/spdbv.Linux: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped
robert@robert-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-CMT-PC:~$ ldd /usr/share/SPDBV/bin/spdbv.Linux
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77cb000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf7673000)
    libXm.so.3 => not found
    libXp.so.6 => not found
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xf7616000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf7603000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xf75f2000)
    libXmu.so.6 => not found
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1 (0xf7515000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0xf74a2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7486000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf746c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7426000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7275000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7253000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf724e000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xf7245000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xf722b000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.304.117 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.304.117 (0xf7226000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.304.117 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libnvidia-glcore.so.304.117 (0xf5520000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf5437000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf541a000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77cc000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf5416000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf540e000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf5408000)*

Comment: How and from where did you install the software? is it 64-bit or 32-bit? Please run `file /usr/share/SPDBV/bin/spdbv.Linux` and `ldd /usr/share/SPDBV/bin/spdbv.Linux` and add the results to your post.

Comment: Is the `libxm4` package installed? And note that if this is a 32-bit program, you'll need `libxm4:i386`.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google took me to [this post](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-elographics/+question/188331), the user there stated that using lucid (I think I can assume you are using ubuntu/debian) they needed to install motif3.

If you can install motif3 (possibly lib3motif) via your package manager that might solve your issue, otherwise you could try:

```
dpkg -S libXm.so.3
```

That should tell you what package in your repositories will provide this library file.

If you have the file installed and it still can't find it then it's probably because the file is somewhere which isn't included in your library path, have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172621/cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory) I think that might help:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If that doesn't make it work, make sure you are running the 64bit version of the operating system, if you're on 32bit look for the 32bit version of the package that includes the library file

Comment: Hi, yes I had also seen this post and unfortunately it didn't help. The file is located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXm.so.3 so I'm not sure why it can't be found. I'll have a further play around today and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope that helps.